# How do I remove the 'Write the Changes to the Disks?' question during preseed?

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, preseed, headless

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux. I have spent a lot of time trying to get an unattended install up and running for my Headless Server.

As it stands I have everything almost there but when testing on VirtuaBox my install asks a question at partitioning 'Write the Changes to the Disks ?'

My Preseed looks like this

```
# echo 'd-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition \
select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean trued-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true' > ks.preseed
```

I could really use some help on this. So close now

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bug of Ubuntu, see:

https://serverfault.com/questions/415174/debian-6-preseeding-keeps-asking-write-the-changes-to-disks-and-configure-lvm

The one required for Ubuntu that appears to be forgotten sometimes is:

```
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.